# Recyclerview refreshing list displaying new list on top of old list

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

My activity consists of recyclerview whose data i am setting on response of an api call.I have added below code inside the success response of an api call.The problem is when i refresh the list on clicking on a button then new list is displayed on top of old list.As a result when i click on list item multiple activities open as the event is also taken by the list behind the current list.Why is this happening?I just want that my list should refresh with new list on clicking on refresh button.How can i resolve this?

```
 @Override
    public void onSuccess(ResponseData responseString) {
     mAdapter = new RowAapter(responseString.getdatd(), mContext);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(mContext, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            startActivity(...);
                        }
                    }));
```

Comment: clear adapter items. addAll new items --> notify

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your adapter and assign it to recyclerView in `OnCreate`

```
private List<ResponseData> responseData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail2);
    mAdapter = new RowAapter(responseData , mContext); 
    recyclerView = ((RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView));
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(ResponseData responseString) {
  responseData.addAll(responseString.getdatd());
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  mList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(mContext, new        RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    startActivity(...);
                }
            }));
```